# Configure default domains for new content

Tags: domain-access

We're using the Domain Access module to assign content to different domains.

When creating new content the default domain record is checked, but not the others.

The desired behavior: Example.com should also be checked by default when creating new content. (regardless of the content type)

Where would this behavior be configured/coded?

[image]

Drupal Version: 9.5.11
Domain Access: 8.x-1.0-beta8

Comment: There isn't a setting to change the default value for that field, which actually is the domain where the node is created. A module could change the default value implementing `hook_form_node_form_alter()`.

Answer (score 0):

As @apaderno mentioned, one possible solution is to manipulate the form field (field_domain_access).

```
function module_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  try {
    if (array_key_exists('field_domain_access', $form)) {
      $node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();

      if ($node->isNew()) {
        $form['field_domain_access']['widget']['#default_value'] = ['www_example_ch', 'www_example_com'];
      }
    }
  } catch(\Throwable $any) {
    \Drupal::logger('global')->info('Exception: %msg', ['%msg' => $any->getMessage() ]);;
  }
}
```

I'm not a big fan of this approach. Probably I don't understand the system good enough yet.